# Angular 2 pipe: Template parse errors: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript, pipe

Following is a JSON data:

```
{
  "tagFrequency": [
    {
      "value": "At",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 249
    },
    {
      "value": "ipsum",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 251
    },
    {
      "value": "molestie",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 199
    }
  ]
}
```

I am populating this data on UI in a table having column names as word, frequency for above JSON object attributes value and count respectively. Third column tag-name is being extracted with GET API call using tagId. Following is my component code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.route.snapshot.url[0].path === 'tag-frequency') {
      let topicId = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

      this.tagService.getTagFrequency(topicId)
      .then(
        (response: any) => {
          this.frequencies = response.json().tagFrequency;
          for (let tagFrequency of this.frequencies) {
            this.getTagName(tagFrequency.tagId);
          }
        }
        )
      .catch(
        (error: any) => console.error(error)
        );
    }
  }

  getTagName(tagId: number) {
    this.tagService.getTag(tagId)
      .then(
        (response: any) => this.tagNames.push(response.name)
        )
      .catch(
        (error: any) => console.error(error)
        );
  }

  sort(value: string) {
    this.direction = this.direction * (-1);
    this.key = value;
  }
}
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th (click)="sort('value')">{{ 'word' | translate }}</th>
          <th>{{ 'tag-name' | translate }}</th>
          <th>{{ 'frequency' | translate }}</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let frequency of frequencies; let i = index | TagFrequencySorter: key: direction">
          <td>{{ frequency.value }}</td>
          <td>{{ tagNames[i] }}</td>
          <td>{{ frequency.count }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I could see all the data in a table correctly if I DO NOT add pipe "TagFrequencySorter" in HTML. If I add, then I am getting an error as:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
>         
>         
>           ]*ngFor="let frequency of frequencies; let i = index | TagFrequencySorter: key: direction">
>            "): TagFrequencyComponent@14:12 Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 45 in [let
>   frequency of frequencies; let i = index | TagFrequencySorter: key:
>   direction] in TagFrequencyComponent@14:12 ("="let frequency of
>   frequencies; let i = index | TagFrequencySorter: key: direction">

I have not used toUpperCase anywhere, not in sort.pipe also. In fact, if I remove this "let i = index" part from below HTML line, then sorting on column "word" is also working. But I need this "index" for populating tagNames array.

```
<tr *ngFor="let frequency of frequencies; let i = index | TagFrequencySorter: key: direction">
```

Can someone tell me how can I get rid of this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to apply the pipe to the local var `index`, is that what you intend to do?

Comment: No I want to apply it on feuencies. So I changed this as <tr *ngFor="let frequency of (frequencies | TagFrequencySorter: key: direction)  let i = index;"> and it worked.